# Determine if there is a matching character on the current line past the cursor

Tags: key-bindings, search

I am trying to make a mapping that performs what `f` would normally do if there is a character match on the line, and to do something else if no such character exists.  For example,
suppose if I had the following line of text.

`The dog _runs fast`,

where the `_` represents my cursor position.  If I press `fa`, I would want my cursor to be on `a` as normal, but if I press `fx`, then I want to add additional functionality.  I have looked into something like retrieving the number of occurrences of a character with `search()`, but I'm don't think there is a range option that only searches the current line past the cursor.

For context, my goal is to make a mapping like `f`, `F`, etc... that wraps around the current line.  So that (in the case of `f`), if there is no matching character past my cursor, it will then search for the same character starting from the beginning of the line.

Thank you

Comment: `search()` does have `stopline`, though there may be easier ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the cursor is in the same position after the forward jump, and, if not, carry out your alternative functionality.

Here's a replacement for `f` to wrap around lines. (It will jump to the start of the line if the character is not on the line. If you want to avoid that, you could include another comparison.)

```
function!Neweff()
        let character = nr2char(getchar())
        let beforejump = getpos('.')
        execute 'norm! f'.character.''
        let afterjump = getpos('.')
        if beforejump == afterjump
                execute 'norm! 0f'.character.''
        endif
endfunction
```

```
nnoremap f :call Neweff()<CR>
```

See `:help getchar()` (there are some nice examples here) and `:help getpos()`.

This doesn't quite answer your question of how to check if there is a character match on the line (one could check if the cursor is in the same position after both a forward and backward match); there's probably a nicer method.

Comment: Thank you!  That helped me with the map for wrapping ```f```.  One modification I made to make it more robust is by adding 
```         
if beforejump == afterjump
            let firstcharacter = getline(".")[0]
            execute 'norm! 0'
            if character !=# firstcharacter
                execute 'norm! f'.character.''
            endif
        endif
``` 
to account for the case in which the searched for character is in column 0.

Comment: I'm not sure how to format multi line code in comments.  If someone knows how, it would be appreciated feedback.

Comment: You check for a match in the line with `getline('.') =~# character`